# Laravel foreign key on migration is not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

i am creating a fresh application on laravel and i am writing the migrations and i want to set the foreign key for my columns so i am doing like below :

```
   Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('type_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('status_id')->default(0);
            $table->integer('category_id')->default(0);
            $table->integer('store_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('product_statuses');
            $table->index('status_id');
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('product_types');
            $table->index('type_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
            $table->index('category_id');
            $table->foreign('store_id')->references('id')->on('stores');
            $table->index('store_id');
```

but these are not working as i check it in `phpmyadmin` it let me insert any number not the item from `status_id` for example and when i check it in `design` tab i dont see the relation between the tables.
#EDIT

adding the `product_types` migration :

```
 /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and about the engine i am using wamp with mysql v8 which i think it sups the fk feature

Comment: I thik the fk column should be `unsigned`. Ie `$table->integer('status_id')->unsigned()` or `$table->bigInteger('status_id')->unsigned()`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ no luck with that i did that but yet no relation among them on phpmyadmin

Comment: Please show us the `product_statuses` migration., and confirm that your DB engine support foreign keys. Ie Innodb (and not myisam) for mysql

Comment: please check it i have added the migration to the question

Comment: Ok, you should use unsignedBigInteger to match the same data type of the related column. Can you confirm that the engine is InnoDB and not MyIsam?

Comment: i am using the unsigned for the columns and yes i confirm that the engine is innoDB

Comment: sorry what i see is that in phpmyadmin on tables there is a column which is writing :Type :MyISAM . is that the same meaning of engine ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you stated in the comments:

> what i see is that in phpmyadmin on tables there is a column which is writing :Type :MyISAM . is that the same meaning of engine ?

Your DB default engine is MyISAM which does not support relational features.

To fix that you can edit your `config/database.php` file, search for `mysql` entry and change:

```
'engine' => null,
```

to

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB',
```

Then you'll have to recreate the tables.

---

If you can't drop and recreate the tables for any reason, you can create a new migration to alter the existing tables. Ie:

```
public function up()
{
    $tables = [
        'product_types',
        'products',
    ];
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE ' . $table . ' ENGINE = InnoDB');
    }
}
```

---

Another thing, it's the data type of the foreign keys columns must match the same data type of the related column.

Since `$table->id()` is an alias of `$table->bigIncrements('id')` as stated in laravel latest versión docs, you should use:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('type_id');

$table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('product_types');
```

Also note the order: create the column first, and the the fk reference (and not the inverse).

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: thanks thats a lot of help and solved my problem <3

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new table in Laravel. The migration will be generated like:
your table should be:
$table->increments('id');

Instead of (in older Laravel versions):

$table->id();

Comment: `$table->id();` =
Alias of `$table->bigIncrements('id')` as stated in laravel latest versión docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types

Comment: i solved the same issue by using this ...that's why I suggested that

Comment: Why did you revert the edit that corrected the grammar and had the code properly formatted?